# Japanese for shirtfronting

Tags: translation

How is the English verb [shirtfront](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/shirtfront), which has a sporting meaning of deliberately colliding into an opponent's chest, knocking them into the ground, and a vague political meaning of confronting another person associated with then Australian Prime Minister Tony Abbott claiming he would confront Vladimir Putin, translated into Japanese?

Is it left in romaji, translated into the katakana シャツフロント, some other option, or did the concept being described fail to enter the Japanese language?

The Japanese edition of Wiktionary [doesn't have a match](https://ja.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%E7%89%B9%E5%88%A5:%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2&profile=default&fulltext=Search&search=shirt%20front&searchToken=cffmp94of1bwwl4fj919mxidy), nor did [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/shirt+front) (apart from quoting the English Wiktionary), nor did jisho.org.

"シャツフロント" "トニー・アボット" got only two google hits, while "shirtfront" "トニー・アボット" or "shirt front" "トニー・アボット" got slightly more hits, but not many.

Comment: Obviously I'm not familiar with the word, and failed to visualize what kind of action it is. Google image search didn't provide much actual "shirtfronting" scenes. Do you have any examples?

Comment: @broccoliforest [shirtfront afl](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=shirtfronting&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1311&bih=778&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRncON86TMAhXIH5QKHUYQDOEQ_AUIBigB#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=shirtfront+afl) became available by going to google image search, searching for shirtfront, and clicking on "afl".

Comment: Thanks. btw Abbott-wise, I've found several articles that report his remark http://jp.sputniknews.com/japanese.ruvr.ru/news/2014_12_10/abotto-pu-chin/ http://www.cnn.co.jp/world/35055184.html http://hayabusa3.2ch.net/test/read.cgi/news/1413195951/ http://memo-no-memo.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2014/11/apec.html when I searched on Google.co.jp with "[アボット プーチン](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%A2%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%83%88+%E3%83%97%E3%83%BC%E3%83%81%E3%83%B3)"

Comment: On a side note, this is the first time I've heard "shirt front", so it might be regional/dialectal to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a Japanese counterpart to shirtfront as a verb, perhaps because Japanese didn't wear a western-style shirt until Meiji era. Our ancestors wore 襦袢 【じゅばん】 (juban).

Instead we have:

1. 胸倉【むなぐら】を掴【つか】む meaning "to grasp sb. by the chest."
2. 頭突【づつ】きを食【く】らわす meaning "to strike sb. (possibly on the chest) with one's head." When you strike sb. with your head, it should be on the other's chest. You can't lower your head so low to hit your enemy's stomach.